# How to Filter an array of objects to find the objects that share cross referencing properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So say for example I'm making a Social app, and I have a user whom I'm trying to make a group match for

```
const user = {Name: Stan, location: "Chicago", preferences: {locations: ["New York"]} }
```

and a collection of people objects like so

```
const matchPool = 
[{Name: Bob, location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago"]} },
 {Name: Susan, location: "Miami", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago", "Miami"]} },
 {Name: Tom, location: "Chicago", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago", "New York"]} },
 {Name: Sally, location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago", "LA"]} },
 {Name: Carl, location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Detroit", "LA", "Chicago"]} }]
```

Say I wanted a group with Stan included, How would I go about filtering so that every member of the group has a location that is in the preferences of every other member of the group?

My first thought was to use lodash with a filter like so

```
const FilteredPeople = _.filter(matchPool, function(matchCandidate) { 
   return user.preferences.locations.indexOf(matchCandidate.location) != -1 &&
          matchCandidate.preferences.locations.indexOf(user.location) != -1
 });
```

If I add Stan to this group returned we would end up with the following

```
 [{Name: Stan, location: "Chicago", preferences: {locations: ["New York"]}} 
  {Name: Bob, location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago"]}},
  {Name: Sally, location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago", "LA"]}},
  {Name: Carl, location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Detroit", "LA", "Chicago"]}}]
```

Notice the issue is that while Stan is an acceptable match for Bob, Sally, and Carl and vice versa, Bob/Sally/Carl are not acceptable matches for each other because none of them have New York as a location preference.

I realize its not possible from this small data set but given I have a large match pool with many people, how would I filter so that ALL people retuned are both compatible with the seed person(Stan) and each other?

Edit: there was some confusion so to say it another way
The location property is where that person is, the preference location array is the cities where that person is willing to meet other people from, so when we form a group all members need to have a location that is in the preference location array of every other member

Comment: Just to clarify - in your sample data, the only user who should end up in the group with Stan is Tom? If so, why are you also checking the potential member's location and not just their preferences?

Comment: Tom wouldnt show up because Stan only wants to meet with people in New York, and Tom is in Chicago

Comment: So in your sample data, Stan could be in a group with any one of Bob, Sally or Carl, just not more than one of them? Does it matter which one you pick?

Comment: @Sully thats correct, Stan could pair with Bob, Sally, Or Carl. However those 3 cant pair with each other. So If I was just trying to make pairs this would be piece of cake. My goal is given a large group in the pool of potential matches find a group of people that all satisfy each others preferences, preferably the largest group possible.

Comment: I feel that this problem is not definite enough. Let's say: `Stan` is the source, and in the first step we get to `Bob`. They are OK with each other, nice. We go forward & then we reach `Sally`. `Stan` & `Bob` is OK, `Stan` & `Sally` is OK, but `Bob` & `Sally` is not OK. Who gets ruled out? `Bob` or `Sally`? Or both? But they both are OK with the source!?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const matchPool = [
{Name: 'Bob', location: 'New York', preferences: {locations: ['Chicago']}},
{Name: 'Susan', location: 'Miami', preferences: {locations: ['Chicago', 'Miami']}},
{Name: 'Tom', location: 'Chicago', preferences: {locations: ['Chicago', 'New York']}},
{Name: 'Sally', location: 'New York', preferences: {locations: ['Chicago', 'LA']}},
{Name: 'Carl', location: 'New York', preferences: {locations: ['Detroit', 'LA', 'Chicago']}},
];

const target = {Name: 'Stan',location: 'Chicago',preferences: { locations: ['New York']}};

let matchGroup = matchPool.filter((user) => {
  if (
    // user in group prefers target's location
    user.preferences.locations.includes(target.location) &&
    // user's location inside targets prefered locations
    target.preferences.locations.includes(user.location)
  ) {
    return user;
  }
});

matchGroup = [target, ...matchGroup];
console.log(JSON.stringify(matchGroup, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this does it for you... it just keeps track of where each match is from to make sure we can check others against the current group. I changed Sally's preferences to include New York so she's included in the matches

```js
const user = {Name: 'Stan', location: "Chicago", preferences: {locations: ["New York"]} }
const matchPool = 
[{Name: 'Bob', location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago"]} },
 {Name: 'Susan', location: "Miami", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago", "Miami"]} },
 {Name: 'Tom', location: "Chicago", preferences: {locations: ["Chicago", "New York"]} },
 {Name: 'Sally', location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["New York","Chicago"]} },
 {Name: 'Carl', location: "New York", preferences: {locations: ["Detroit", "LA", "Chicago"]} }]
 
let matches=[]
let locs = [user.location] 
matchPool.forEach(m=>{
    //If a user from the pool matches, add them and also keep track of their location to ensure future matches
  if (user.preferences.locations.indexOf(m.location)>-1 && locs.every(val => m.preferences.locations.includes(val))){
        matches.push(m)
    locs.push(m.location)
  } 
})

console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm could look like this:

1. Start with a source - filter the `db` to all items that match. This is the "base-lvl0" (it ensures that our source cannot be ruled out later)
2. Take the 1. element from the "base-lvl0", and use it as the "source" for a second iteration to produce a "base-lvl1-1"
3. Take the 2. element from the "base-lvl0", and use it as the "source" for a second iteration to produce a "base-lvl1-2"
4. Take the 3. element from the "base-lvl0", and use it as the "source" for a second iteration to produce a "base-lvl1-3"

...

n. Take the nth element from the "base-lvl0" and use it as the "source" for a second iteration to produce a "base-lvl1-n"

By the nth step, you'll have a lot of smaller groups that are sure to satisfy at least 2 people. Now, do this with all the "base-lvl1-x" lists to create "base-lvl2-x" lists (to surely satisfy 3 people), then comes "base-lvl3-x", etc. up until all items from all lists have been used as "source".

This way you make sure that in all the FINAL lists everyone is in the preferential lists of everyone. I think this is a bit inefficient but deterministic & sure to satisfy the "location & preferred location" condition.

#### SUGGESTION:

Try to loosen up the conditions a bit or start to get deep into the beauties of graph theory.

This is quite cutting edge maths, and I think resembles your problem (in some ways): [A Breakthrough in Graph Theory - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tnu_Ws7Llo4) (2019)